# Why was my question on high-performance-networking put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[testing network connectivity on a server with Gigabit Ethernet](https://serverfault.com/questions/526287/testing-network-connectivity-on-a-server-with-gigabit-ethernet)

Let me quote the bolded out part from the question:

- **only control one server**
- **tool that would let me download a 100MB file in several simultaneous TCP streams over HTTP**

Now, let's just do some common-sense math in regards to the concept of **Bandwidth Delay Product**, based on the **20MB/s** from the question and **25 ms** from my comment as a reply to someone else's comment.

20 MB/s * 25 ms ≈ 512 KB

Wow, quite a round number and quite a big buffer, I wonder whether it's a coincidence that one's throughput is indeed limited by 200Mbps in one's tests with single-stream downloads?

Now, a bunch of yahoos came in, and flooded the question with irrelevant answers about internet pipes, about how connection speed is irrelevant, about how networks have congestion, and just about all kinds of variables other than what the question has been asking for -- **command-line tool similar to wget with simultaneous download support**.

I didn't babysit these answers, and the "community" has then decided to put my question on hold with the following reason:

- "Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See How can I ask better questions on Server Fault? for further guidance." – MDMarra, Scott Pack, mdpc, Falcon Momot, Nathan C

Oh, pardon me, yes, I'm obviously a clueless monkey that has no understand of bandwidth delay product or some beyond-basic internet connectivity issues like speed of the interface vs. the speed of the overall connection.

Shouldn't **people who vote to close a question** demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**?

BTW, thanks to one humble user, tomodachi, I was able to confirm that my connection is indeed 1Gbps, since he actually answered what I was asking for. :-)

But I'm overall disappointed that this situation happens so often on various SE sites: people have no clue what the question is about, so, they just vote to close it in their own ignorance, especially after their own misinformed answers have received a negative attention or rating.

And it is a problem.

Comment: I'm one of the 5 that voted to close that, but ticked the wrong radio box. I meant to close it as a product rec. That said, I've also voted to reopen after reading this and re-reading the question. There's a lot of garbage on the site lately and I think some of us have been a little trigger-happy lately. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to be extremely blunt, because it's after midnight here and I'm cranky:

**In short what's wrong with your question is that instead of including all of this relevant information that you decided to post on meta in a great fit of offense you chose to throw a turd against our window and then asked us to use Google for you.**

The Google part I can forgive (because I tried a few obvious searches, *knowing* I would recommend Aria or a few other tools for multi-streaming downloads, and I didn't get useful results with that foreknowledge). **Your question is, as a whole, on-topic.**

The turd part I can't. **Your question needs some additional effort in order to be "professional quality".**

---

### If you [ask a **good** question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) people will be happy to help you.

Good questions tell us what you've researched and eliminated.
We shouldn't HAVE to tell you about bandwidth delay product, buffer bloat, route saturation, *etc.*: [As a professional](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) you should have some research, determined whether or not these things are a factor, *and shown us your work so we don't have to rehash it and waste everyone's time*.

Of course we don't expect you to figure out EVERYTHING on your own - you wouldn't need us if that were the case! We just want to see that you've done *something* and aren't just taking the lazyweb way out.

> If you want to improve your question and have it reopened take a few minutes of your time to edit it to include the details you've provided here. Make it a ***professional quality question*** that shows you take your work seriously, and aren't just asking the internet to do all the thinking for you.
>
> Remember that we only know what you tell us, so let us know that *you* know delay isn't a major factor, and that the remote site can meet or exceed your server's available bandwidth (and if you aren't sure tell us that -- it's important, and influences our recommendations).

---

## We aren't doing this to be mean.

Please don't take having your question closed personally. We really don't care who you are - we care about whether or not *the question* meets our standards for quality and topicality.

Pitching a fit on Meta is not the way to handle this sort of thing.
It just results in your question sitting, closed, for a longer period of time while we wait for you to improve it.

If you had taken 15 minutes to include the relevant information in your question it would be reopened already and I wouldn't be wasting my evening giving you a lecture.

You'd be happier, I'd be happier, and the community would have a good question about performing real-world bandwidth tests, that will attract good *detailed* answers (as opposed to just a link to a multi-streaming download tool).

Answer (score 8):

I didn't touch your question, and didn't even read it until now, but I do want to make the following observations:

- First, the question says nothing about bandwidth delay product, TCP slow start, or any other relevant issue. Thus it's perfectly reasonable to assume that whoever asked the question is ignorant of these issues.
- Questions asking for [product, service and learning material recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) aren't permitted here. While we could reopen the question, without a bit of rewriting, we'd just have to close it again for that reason.
- As Nathan C noted, rudeness is a really bad idea. Not only is it also [not permitted here](https://serverfault.com/help/behavior), it will also annoy the people you are seeking help from. Not a good way to start a relationship...

Comment: [***Chuch!!!***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chuch)

Comment: Well, but none of the answers actually start telling me about BDP!

Comment: It's not a service recommendation question, it's a question on how to accomplish a certain task that is not being accomplished.  It's a pretty specific question.

Comment: If you didn't mean it to be a request for a product recommendation, then you should edit it. It still appears to be exactly that.

Comment: Michael, could you care to explain why my question is not within the "Safe Harbour" provisions of the Let's Go Shopping post you reference?  Also, even according to your first point, shouldn't every single answer then educate me about BDP?  If so, why not a single one does (and one of the 3 offtopic answers, by spuder, has just apparently been deleted, after receiving 2 negative votes).  The 75% of answers had nothing to do with the question, and the 25% answer was merely a comment, and not an actual answer, and you're surprised why I didn't act extra thankful for such bogus answers?

Answer (score 2):

It's an awful question.

You have GigE and are complaining that you can't download at 100MBps from some random site? Please.

Listen buddy, the Internet is the Wild West. You have NO IDEA what's going on in between you and the other server.

Maybe it's rate limiting you. Maybe you don't have GbE. Maybe the tubes are saturated with pictures of crap depicting the Royal Baby on Etsy.

Oh, wait, your NIC shows 1GbE negotiated. I guess you must have High Performance connectivity. How cute. Have a biscuit.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't be any more rude with your comments, could you? The close reasons are not meant to be taken personally.

For what it's worth, I VTC'd the topic because the answer can be easily found on [insert search engine here] and a few minutes of research. That, and even though people provided additional information to your issue, comments like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/526287/testing-network-connectivity-on-a-server-with-gigabit-ethernet#comment600476_526305) are just making people not want to answer you.

Just a bit of friendly advice: when asking a question, please instead just not upvote/accept wrong answers. Everyone here is a volunteer and no one's right 100% of the time.

Comment: Please kindly provide a duckduckgo link which has the "tons" of tools that you're referring to.

Comment: The original answer, to my comment of which you're referring, was basically just a link to one such tool, without any kind of basic info on how to use it in a simple way that fits the question, and it originally even contained information that was outright wrong.  I believe it is an SE policy that a link is not an answer.  The answer has since been amended, and is now quite satisfactory.

Comment: @cnst Then, it's helpful to point out how to improve instead of saying "it's plain wrong". Think about how you'd react if you saw someone respond to an answer like that you spent time researching.

Comment: If you have no clue of the subject matter, why are you rushing to answer?  Also, I did actually point people out in the right direction, it's not exactly my fault that it fell on death ears: my explicit hints were missed by so many people that have, apparently, NEVER heard of BDP, yet thought they're qualified to answer a question on GigE internet (not LAN).

Comment: By the way, [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/download-accelerator-for-linux-command-line-tools.html) was the first result of a Google search. Terrible search engines don't count.

Comment: And, BTW, are you kidding me?  This is my exact comment: **Completely false; you're limited by the network buffers of TCP on both ends in scenarios that involve real broadband connections. – cnst 7 hours ago**, to which you've trolled, **@cnst That's not correct. Slower links don't magically go faster because a bigger pipe said to. – Nathan C 7 hours ago**

Comment: wow, thank you for showing more ignorance!  I'm still to receive the search phrase you've used that provides just so many different tools to choose from.  The whole point of duckduckgo, BTW, is that it doesn't give different answers to different users, and it's actually based on Google and Bing.

Comment: @cnst [Here you go](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=linux+multiple+download+tool&oq=linux+multiple+download+tool&gs_l=hp.12..33i29i30l4.591.591.0.1966.1.1.0.0.0.0.177.177.0j1.1.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.AGCeBftQErk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469%2Cd.dmg%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=30ae1b1e5770a225&biw=1920&bih=965)