# Suggestion: removal or rename of the "rebuild" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag happens in most cases with raid or with other non-trivial sector-mapped storage solution. But its standalone meaning is at least unclear or too broad.

My suggestion were to

1. Either delete this tag,
2. Or rename it to rebuild-raid or raid-rebuild (or to rebuild-storage, or any similar),
3. Or split this to rebuild-raid, rebuild-crypto, etc.

Comment: It looks like only [one question](http://serverfault.com/q/119139/207703) has the `rebuild` tag and no other tags. I've suggested an edit to add some other tags.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort to retags questions with [rebuild] tags. Next time you [do it again](http://serverfault.com/users/200053/peterh?tab=activity), please slow it down so the [old questions didn't cluttered frontpage](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6783/can-anything-be-done-about-mods-robo-rejecting-edits-that-are-objective-improvem). Our mod suggest that [you need to keep edits that bump old content to around 2 an hour (or less)](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7937/cleanup-duplicate-tags-different-by-hyphenation-and-pluralization#comment17005_7937)

Comment: Task done. The now unused tag will be automatically deleted in a day. The list of changes can you see [here](http://serverfault.com/users/200053/peterh?tab=activity&sort=revisions), I hope I didn't committed any destructive. If there is no reaction here, I will accept the most upvoted answer and consider the thing ready.

Comment: @masegaloeh I am sorry, I've just now read your comment! Ok, next time I will do it slower.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having had a quick look at the 50 questions tagged [rebuild](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rebuild) I'd be inclined to agree with 1. deletion.

It doesn't always appear as though people wanted to use it as [raid-rebuild](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/raid-rebuild) etc so just removing it seems like a good option.

Comment: Agreed - "rebuild" as a tag is less than useless. (***WHAT*** are you rebuilding? A RAID array? A server? A house in Miami?)