# Reasonable business information technology management practices

Tags: discussion

My question got closed due to not showing "reasonable business information technology management practices". What counts as such 'reasonable management practices'?

Comment: This question is intended to eventually be the link in the close-reason of this title. Please speak clearly, it's for posterity. Shall we begin?

Comment: Before we do this, we should think about altering this close reason. Plainly spoken, it's crap.

Comment: @Sven Might be worth waiting, but at the same time, I think that "reasonable business information technology management practices" is the core of the newly worded close reason, and was the gist of the old one too, so it seems like it's probably safe to assume that phrase won't be going away.  I also disagree that the new close reason is crap...  Sure, I'd prefer it say `because you're "doing it wrong," dumbass`, but since that's not gonna happen... well, I think the new wording strikes a good balance between plainly explaining what's wrong, while being SE *pink-and-fluffy* compatible.

Comment: I'd try and take a crack at this one, but as shown [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6812/proposed-change-to-server-fault-guidelines-round-2#comment15701_6832) I was confused by it myself.  Even Shane Madden doesn't like it, but it was the best he could come up with to replace the "not professional".  I agree with @HopelessN00b in that it's a fluffy bunny version of "wth are you thinking?"

Comment: @HopelessN00b: The problem I have with it is that I am not sure I really understand it myself - it sounds like written by a politician (sorry Shane...) and I really hesitate to use it because of this. As an example: If you don't know about the discussions we had, how should you understand what we mean with "unmaintained environment"?

Comment: I don't know. Personally I'm about five minutes away from removing this close reason, as I can't even understand why it was used sometimes.

Comment: @Sven Right, which, among other reasons, is why it would really be better if we just came out and said `This question is being closed because you're doing wrong and/or clearly don't have a clue.  Ask again if or when you decide to approach the problem with actual standards, like a professional would.`  But we can't, and SE seems entrenched in keeping things *pink-and-fluffy*, which is why it's confusing.  There's just no *pink-and-fluffy* way to tell someone they're doing it incompetently, like a brain-damaged monkey would.

Comment: I don't even have a clue what I'm supposed to close or leave open any more.

Comment: So that we're not derailing this question, I've started a new one for "how can we fix this thing": http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7850/what-can-we-do-to-fix-the-reasonable-management-practices-close-reason

Comment: @HopelessN00b Hence I'm developing my own personal library of close reasons. :D I'll probably be the reason that StackExchange removes the custom close reason from ServerFault though. Everyone start hating me in advance.

Comment: @Wesley I'm doing something similar, although my interest in voting on anything has largely disappeared lately.  ps get a bike!

Comment: Well, this went well.