# Question about "Amazon API gateway" put on hold at Server Fault

Tags: discussion

The reason is stated as "off-topic":

```
"Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment.
Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on **Super User**,
and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on **Stack Overflow**."
```

This is not and end-user question, or not anything related to programming or development. It's a question about "managing server stack" which I believe comes under the scope of Server Fault.

Question:
*[Link Amazon API gateway to Django](https://serverfault.com/questions/877941/link-amazon-api-gateway-to-django)*

Comment: We are a site for professionals managing information technology systems in a business environment and as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that you will have done some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. Only then can you  [write that great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer. -
 Your question doesn't show any of that and would have been closed by me for that reason alone, regardless.

Comment: I have done a week of research before posting a question, @HBruijn this is not a satisfying answer.

Comment: It is not enough to do the research; you also need to apply it when you are writing your question. It would also be a good idea to spend a little more research time on following [the link in the comment](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681).

Comment: @JennyD it might be  a good  idea not to use servrfult anymore.  Adios

Comment: As orher stated about dev tool, a good example that look like your question (on SO) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756663/api-gateway-vs-reverse-proxy

Comment: As I mentioned **your question doesn't show** what research you did, instead it gives me ***the impression*** that you didn't invest any effort yet (but expect our community to do).

Answer (score 3):

In the words of Amazon that is functionality designed for developers and that makes the question almost always [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for Server Fault:

> [**Amazon API Gateway**](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)
>   Amazon API Gateway is a fully managed service that **makes it easy for developers** to create, publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs at any scale. With a few clicks in the AWS Management Console, you can create an API that acts as a “front door” for applications to access ... any Web application.

Comment: Then why is "amazon-api-gateway" tag avaliable in serverfault. ?

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa: Mainly, because everyone with 300 reputation points can create tags. Also, while I can't come up with an example right now, I can imagine that there might be questions that involve this topic that are on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have used that specific close reason, but instead would have had to choose between "no clear problem statement" and "reasonable practices" (oh how I wish that the close reason selector used checkboxes, not radio buttons).  "My employer told me to" isn't a valid reason for choosing a design (you're *supposed* to be a professional, not an unthinking mouse jockey), and you haven't done any of the things that are required for a question to meet the "clear problem statement" hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are excellent, but I think we need to be honest with the poor OP about this.  A long time ago, SF used to have an explicit mission statement that it was for and about professional sysadmin.  We had a close reason that said

> Questions must be relevant to professional system administration. Server Fault is dedicated to professional system and network administrators. End user and enthusiast questions are off-topic (contact your system administrator or hire a professional to help you out).

[This went away](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6714/remove-professional-close-reason) and was replaced the with the anodyne pair:

> Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

and

> Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices.

Opinion is divided about *why* it went away.  But at least some of us hairy old-timers felt that SE management was upset about the "unfriendly" reputation SF was getting, because we ruthlessly closed-out questions that were from people who clearly *needed* a sysadmin, rather than people who *were* sysadmins.

The problem is that management can mess about with the language all it likes, but it can't make us *want* to provide an endless flow of free sysadmin help to people who have not yet learned their basic professional skillset.  At least some of us didn't, and still don't, want to do that.

So instead some of us, myself included, use the two new close reasons above as Sekrit Kode (tm) for *you're trying to do a thing no professional would do* and/or *you're trying to do a thing in a way no professional would do it* (those two are related, but importantly different).

I agree that there is no way some poor person who's wandered in can know this history.  I agree that a disservice is being done to people who get their questions closed for reasons which aren't really those stated.  I feel that you, Ryu_hayabusa, are owed an apology because you've got caught in this particular crossfire (though your attitude in the comments above is very poor).   I just don't agree about whose fault it is, and who owes you the apology.