# Where is the best place to ask question about servers but also when "learning new things"?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

Being attracted from the name "ServerFault" I thought this was the best StackExchange site to ask about servers which I own with AWS.

But when going through [the tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) and some [meta questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/4111/134401), I realized that what I was going to ask on this site was not on-topic here.

The questions I was intending to ask here are off-topic because:

- They are not for business environment, but for development environment.
- They are result of hit and trial and experimentation.

My point is.. I own some EC2 instances to learn new things. Maybe one day I'll be doing those things in a production/business environment. But what about the question I am having right now?

### Edit 1

I have question about Nginx, Jenkins, OpenVPN, DNS, CDN.. where do those go?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of sites more welcoming of learners:

- [For general Ubuntu-related issues, try Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [For nerdy Linux/Unix related questions, try Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- [For automating management of EC2 instances, including how they relate to software development infrastructure, try DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)
- [The catch-all home of all things learning is SuperUser](https://superuser.com) (the highest traffic of the four)

I'm not sure where in the Stack is the best home for learning AWS-specific things, but DevOps isn't a terrible choice.